# Add Static ARP Entry at Boot

Tags: macos, terminal, startup, launchd

I'm new to Mac OS X.
On Linux I'd:

```
append to /etc/rc.local
arp -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.1 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I've figured out how to do it in Terminal:

```
sudo arp -s 192.168.1.1 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

But I'd like this to happen automatically preferably at boot.
Also do I need to specify an interface when using `arp`?

I read some other SE answers that mentioned launchd, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: I've found this http://books.google.com.au/books?id=A54wEFXr5KUC&lpg=PA237&ots=K6adg7d-md&dq=static%20arp%20entry%20boot%20mac%20os%20x&pg=PA237#v=onepage&q=static%20arp%20entry%20boot%20mac%20os%20x&f=false does anyone know if `/Library/StartupItems` still exists in Mavericks?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a lot with Matthieu's solution since it caused two problems on my Mac OS X 10.9.2:

1. Jobs in the `LaunchAgents` folder are executed using the current user. However `arp` needs to be executed using `root`.
2. The `arp`-command is executed too early, when the network is not up. But the network is needed by the `arp`-command.

The first problem can be solved by storing the `.plist` file in `LaunchDaemons` instead of `LaunchAgents`. This will ensure that the command is executed as root.

The second problem is a bit tricky. Since `launchd` does not handle dependencies, we have to write our own shell script which first waits until the network is up an then execute the `arp` command. (See [here](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2010/07/01/how-to-run-a-launchdaemon-that-requires-networking/))

**So here is my solution:**
First create/open the plist file using a text-editor:

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.arpentries.plist
```

Then paste the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.arpentries</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/arpentries</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Set owner etc.:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.arpentries.plist
sudo chmod 0644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.arpentries.plist
```

Now create/open the shell script using a text editor

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/arpentries
```

Paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# max number of retries
retries=10

# include Startup commons
. /etc/rc.common

# wait for network to become available
CheckForNetwork

while [ "$NETWORKUP" != "-YES-" ]
do
        retries=$((retries - 1))
        if [ $retries -le 0 ] ; then
                exit 1
        fi
        sleep 2
        NETWORKUP=
        CheckForNetwork
done

# set the static arp entries
arp -s 192.168.1.111 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

exit 0
```

And the rights:

```
sudo chmod 0744 /usr/local/bin/arpentries
```

Comment: You can also use crankd to set the arp entries each time the network changes. One thing to note is that the PyMacAdmin-download from googlecode throws an exception (at least on my Mac OS). Using the source code and the install-script from Github works fine however.

Comment: Oh wow, I've been struggling with this still. I was going to try with LaunchAgents and sudo NOPASSWD. I'll give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

[`Launchd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) is a daemon  that starts, stops and manages daemons, applications, processes, and scripts on OSX. It's intended to replace unix' cron.

Create a new `.plist` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.arpentry</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/arp</string>
        <string>-s</string>
        <string>192.168.1.1</string>
        <string>00:00:00:00:00:00</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Nice</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then move your new `.plist` to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` so it will loaded every time you log into your session and therefore run you command everytime you log in.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a GUI for plists or something to help me make them next time?

Comment: ~/Library/LaunchAgents doesn't exist but /Library/LaunchAgents does

Comment: Jobs in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` will be run whenever *you* log in. This directory does not exist on a fresh installation of OSX and has to be created manually. Jobs in `/Library/LaunchAgents` will be run whenever *any*  user logs in. [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl) is a GUI for launchd/launchctl.

Comment: For those reading this in the future I found this: http://ptone.com/cron2launchd/

Comment: Xcode has an integrated GUI to edit/create `.plist` files.

Comment: I've put it in /Library/LaunchAgents as I want to to happen on boot, but it doesn't seem to work. arp -a doesn't show the entry. Do I need to chown it as root?

Comment: arp -s requires root/sudo so I'm thinking you can't run on login?

Comment: If you want to run it as root, you might want to add it as a LaunchDaemon in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. Daemons as run as Root whereas Agents are run as the user.

Comment: hmm, the arp entry isn't present on boot. Are there logs I can check that might tell me what is going on?

Comment: So I used the console and found "dubious ownership on file". Googling now will report back on a solution.

Comment: sudo chown root:wheel <filename>

Comment: I'll report back when I restart if that fixed it.

Comment: damn, didn't fix it

Comment: com.apple.launchd[1]: (local.arpentry[81]) Exited with code: 1

Comment: I've worked this down to: arp: writing to routing socket: File exists

Comment: changed to `arp -S ip mac` now getting arp: writing to routing socket: No such process